# Quando chamar super.nomeMetodo ao sobrescrever(Override) um método?

Tags: java, android

Em uma classe temos vários métodos sobrepostos com o `@Override`, e em alguns, por exemplo o `onPreExecute` de uma classe estendida da `AsyncTask`, já vem com o `super.onPreExecute()`.

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
```

O que seria esse método `super.nomeDoMetodo()` e quando deve-se deixar ou não deixar essa chamada ao método da classe superior?

Comment: Editei a pergunta para que se torne mais objetiva, veja se é isso mesmo.

Comment: Só faltou "o que seria" este método super que algumas tem e outras não, e sim quando deixá-lo ou não.  ;)

Comment: Adiciona la, até bom que já tem 2 respostas e eles atualizam. :)

Comment: O método `super` é utilizado para executar o código do método "pai". As vezes é necessário deixar (vide o código das *activities*). Mas quando não há um código obrigatório no método "pai", essa linha se torna desnecessária.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ao escrever uma classe que extends de outra é possível sobrescrever os seus métodos.

Ao fazê-lo está a escrever outra implementação, sendo a implementação original descartada/sobrescrita.

No entanto, há casos que, devido à forma como a classe foi implementada, é necessário que a implementação original do método sobrescrito seja executada.

A forma de fazê-lo é usar `super.nomeMetodoSobrescrito()`.

Quando é um método abstracto nunca é necessário fazê-lo.
Nos outros casos deve fazê-lo quando a documentação da classe assim o indicar.

No que diz respeito ao Android SDK, pelo menos no uso da classe Activity, será lançada um excepção se o não fizer.
Se, no Android Studio, usar **Generate... -> Override Methods...** a chamada ao método será automaticamente colocada quando é necessária.

Comment: Eu penso da seguinte forma: Eu sobrepus o método com o `@Override`, mas ainda estou trazendo todo conteúdo dele com o `super.nomeMetodo()` e implementando com a minha necessidade, correto !?

Comment: Sim é isso mesmo.

Answer (score 5):

AsyncTask é uma classe abstrata com alguns métodos cuja implementação padrão não faz nada, entre eles o onPreExecute().

Esses métodos devem ser sobrescritos (implementados) pelas subclasses de AsyncTask.

Ou seja, não existe implementação padrão de onPreExecute(). Não é preciso chamar super.onPreExecute() pois esta chamada não fará nada. Isso vale para alguns métodos da classe AsyncTask.

Há situações em que chamar o super faz sentido. Isto é (ou pelo menos deveria ser) documentado no Javadoc do método ou da classe. Por exemplo, ao sobrescrever Activity.onCreate(). Nesse caso já existe uma implementação padrão na superclasse que deve ser complementada com o método sobrescrito na subclasse.

"super" é uma referência à superclasse. Assim como "this" é uma referência ao próprio objeto. Chamar método() é o mesmo que chamar this.método(), e chamar super.método() irá invocar a versão "pai" do método, isto é, a implementação feita na superclasse.